# Internal ASP.NET Web Application deployment to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, intranet

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application that I am deploying to an IIS 6.0 web server. My ASP.NET application is being deployed as a virtual directory. Currently, this ASP.NET application is publicly visible on the internet. However, I need the ASP.NET application to run only inside of my corporate firewall.

How do I configure my application so that individuals outside of my company canNOT access/use the web application?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do one of the following:

if your app is standalone
1: create separate site for your application with DNS host name that is internal

if not 
2: apply security to your virtual directory (windows auth can be seamless)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest,

1. Use the corporate firewall to block all external requests to this IIS server. Consult your IT guys, as that's quite easy for them to do that for you.
2. Or use IP policy in IIS Manager to allow internal IP range but block all others. This is simply a workaround, which has worse performance than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a question best suited for ServerFault but you will need to have an IP address that is only internally viewable from the corporate firewall.  You probably have an IT department so ask them for a internal only IP address and then assign the IP address they give you in IIS.